# delete row for sqlite3 use WHERE condition

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some problems use DELETE function in sqlite3 I try to delete a row from some tables by passing the name of the table using .formt like that :

```
def delete_record_from_table(self, table_name, username):
    self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM {} WHERE username =?".format(table_name), (username,))
```

there is no problem with the ran it not return an error but when I print the table the row wasn't delete

if I pass the real name of the table the row delete

Comment: Do you call `connection.commit()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deletes and inserts, you have to `commit` the connection object used to create the cursor object by running `conn.commit()`

Here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) on how to use connection

Also be sure to `close` your connection when you're finished